# Apache does not load default webpage after installing

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a Vultr server and followed this tutorial (yeah, 2 commands) to install Apache on Ubuntu:
https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-linux-apache-mysql-and-php-lamp-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/#

Apache is running and up-to-date

`curl localhost:80` shows the sample file

```
nc -vz 95.179.207.106 22
Connection to 95.179.207.106 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

I haven't touched anything, nor the firewall, but I checked its status:

```
sudo ufw status

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly thing, I checked firewall and it didn't allow connections on port 80. After I enabled it worked. Tutorials nowadays seem to miss so much thing that even a mysql install can take hours.